# How can I avoid "missing dependency" in useEffect by useRef?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
  const increaseNumber = useRef({});
  increaseNumber.current = async () => {
    await setTimeout(() => {
      setNum(num + 1);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    increaseNumber.current();
  }, []);
```

Error at **current()**:
(property) React.MutableRefObject<{}>.current: {}
This expression is not callable.
Type '{}' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Comment: The error doesn't say "missing dependency" it says `{}` is not callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `increaseNumber` to an empty object instead of a function.

`const increaseNumber = useRef({});`

Try:

```js
  const increaseNumber = useRef(async () => {
    await setTimeout(() => {
      setNum(num + 1);
    });
  });
```